# Bar chart, like bootstrap progress bar

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar, bar-chart

I am trying to achieve this below:

[image]

I basically want these to represent data i'm pulling from database. But i cannot figure out hour to achieve this.

So i figured i can possibly use bootstrap progress bar but style it a little different.

This is how it would be in html
http://www.bootply.com/QOwn8Bs0wY

Does anyone know how i can now change the lines to be a lot closer?

I think its to do with these css styles in bootstrap.

```
 -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 25%,transparent 25%,transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%,transparent 75%,transparent)
```

But i cannot replicate the picture.

Comment: .progress-bar-striped {
  
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    135deg,
    #464,
    #8f8 3px,
    #868 1px
  )
}

Comment: good, but not looking close enough

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
background-color: gray;
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 5px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 5px, rgba(255,255,255,.5) 10px);
```

I modified [this](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#diagonal-stripes) a bit, it's easier to understand than the bootstrap one. Then don't forget to make it cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.progress {border-radius:0;}
.progress-bar-striped, .progress-striped .progress-bar {
    linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-size: 7px 7px;
}
```